# How to append data(new row) at new line or row to existing csv file by using fast-csv npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, npm, fs

I am trying to add/write data to existing csv file using 'fast-csv' npm. But it's appending new data to be written in the last row written in file it's not writing a new row for it as headers are also same.

I have tried below code for appending data:

```
csv.writeToStream(fs.createWriteStream('test.csv', { flags: 'a' }), [dataObj], { headers: false }).on("finish", function() {
                console.log("file written successfully")
 })
```

want to know  is there any way to add data to new row ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might need to configure the ***includeEndRowDelimiter*** as ***true***, please check the docs at:
[fast-csv document, section Formatting](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv). Lets try the following:

```js
{ flags: 'a', includeEndRowDelimiter: true }
```

Comment: this is not working in, i checked with fast-csv 2.2.0